# Dynamic cell height based on content ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I working on a app which loads the posts of user on facebook. All this info is put into a tableview. The cells are expendable when you tap on it. For now there is only text in it. I calculate the height of the text so I know how high the cell needs to be when expanded.

Problem which I having is that there needs to be more than only text in it. If the user posts a video on facebook the video will also be embedded in the cell. But since the height is calculated based on the text it leaves no room for the embedded video. I can add a margin in the cell but this margin will be applied to al the cell then.

This is the code which I am using right now:

```
//Function executes everything within when a certain row in tapped/selected
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{    
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self stopLoading];
    if (selectedIndexPath == indexPath) 
    {         
        selectedIndexPath = nil;
    }
    else 
    {        
        selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
    }          
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath : indexPath animated : YES];
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView endUpdates];
}

//Change heigth of the selected row
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    if ((selectedIndexPath != nil) && (selectedIndexPath.row == indexPath.row)) 
    {
        labelSize = [[result2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:13.0] 
                                                                  constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(220.0f, MAXFLOAT) 
                                                                lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
        return labelSize.height + 136;

    }
    return 68.0;
}
```

So what I need to know. How can I calculate to height of the cell based on al the content? and not only the text.

Would be great if somebody can help with this!

Thnx in advance

Comment: Actually.. it was pretty simple.

Just had to add the following in heightForRowAtIndexPath

  

      NSString *video = [fbSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ;
        if (video != @"empty") {
            return labelSize.height + 136;
        }
           return labelSize.height + 36;

Comment: You should post that as an answer and then accept it, so this question no longer shows up as unanswered.

Comment: yeah, that wasn't possible yet. I needed to wait 8 hours, but did it now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually.. it was pretty simple. Just had to add the following in heightForRowAtIndexPath

```
    NSString *video = [fbSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ; 
    if (video != @"empty") { return labelSize.height + 136; } 
    return labelSize.height + 36;
```